# Nestjs using accessToken on another route return Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, jwt, nestjs, passport.js, passport-jwt

Consider that I have two routes in NestJS, called "signUp" and "validate-code", both of which are inside the SignupModule.
 For the signUp route, I return an accessToken using JWT. Here's the code:

```js
const payload = {
    mobileNumber: user.mobileNumber
};

return [
    {...userData,accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),}
];
```

After sending the mobile number as a request using Postman to the server, everything works fine and I get an accessToken.

Now, I want to use this accessToken to authorize the validate-code route and check if the user has already registered and their information exists in the database. I have to send the mobileNumber and code to this route along with the accessToken that I received previously through the signUp route. I set the accessToken in Postman as Bearer, but it gives me the following message:

```json
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

The classes written for JWT are as follows:

```js
import {Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";
import {AuthGuard} from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------
import {AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';
import {Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------
import {PassportStrategy} from "@nestjs/passport";
import {ExtractJwt} from "passport-jwt";
import {Strategy} from "passport-local";

export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            passReqToCallback: true,
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: any) {
        return {
            mobileNumber: payload.mobileNumber
        };
    }
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------
import {Injectable, UnauthroziedException} from "@nestjs/common";
import {PassportStrategy} from "@nestjs/passport";
import {Strategy} from 'passport-local';
import {SignupService} from "./signup.service";

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private readonly signupService: SignupService) {
        super();
    }

    async validate(mobileNumber: string) {
        const user = await this.signupService.validateUser(mobileNumber);
        if (!user) {
            throw  new UnauthroziedException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

The signUp route in the SignupController:

```js
@Post('signup')
async signUp(@Body() dto: SignupDto, @Res() res: Response):Promise<Response<any,Record<string, any>>> {
    const result = await this.authService.signUp(dto.mobileNumber);
    return res.status(result ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({'message':result});
}
```

The validate-code route in the SignupController:

```js
@UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
@Post('validate-code')
async validateCode(@Body() dto:VerifyCodeDto,@Res() res:Response):Promise<Response<any,Record<string, any>>>{
    const [statusCode,data] = await this.authService.verifyCode(dto);
    return res.status(statusCode).json(data);
}
```

Finally, the SignupModule is implemented to use JWT and Passport:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
            signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
        }),
        ThrottlerModule.forRoot(
            {
                ttl: 30,
                limit: 6
            }
        ),
        PrismaModule,
        ApiModule
    ],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [
        JwtStrategy,
        LocalStrategy,
        SignupService,
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useClass: ThrottlerGuard
        }
    ]
})
export class SignupModule {
}
```

[image]

[image]

So, I have no problem with the signUp route and getting the accessToken, but I cannot use it for the validate-code route. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen for two reasons:

1. the `validate` function didn't run at all: this may occur when the token is not valid or already expired, you have to verify that `process.env.JWT_SECRET` is properly passed to `secret` and `secretOrKey`. also make sure the token created is encrypted with the same string. if the token is not valid or expired then the `validate` function will not run and you get `Unauthorized` as `message` value in the response.
2. the `validate` function is running but `this.signupService.validateUser(mobileNumber)` is returning a "falsy" result so `user` is not defined therefore `new UnauthroziedException()` is thrown.

**Note:** I usually work with only one strategy but here you are using two
the first one:

```js
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') 
//...
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt')
```

the second one:

```js
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local')
//...
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy)
```

then you add `@UseGuards()` with `LocalAuthGuard` to your `@Post('validate-code')` route but I can't see from the code any indication that `LocalAuthGuard` should use `LocalStrategy` as strategy, make sure the expected `validate` function is running.

from [Nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#named-strategies) about named strategies:

> When implementing a strategy, you can provide a name for it by passing a second argument to the PassportStrategy function. If you don't do this, each strategy will have a default name (e.g., 'jwt' for jwt-strategy):

```js
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'myjwt')
```

> Then, you refer to this via a decorator like `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('myjwt'))`